# MySQL exception after upgrading from Java 6 to Java 7

Tags: mysql

I've been trying, for a long time, to find a solution for the issue.

Recently I've updated my JDK from 6 to 7. Now my grails app doesn't start up, I keep getting the follow exception:

```
Caused by SQLException: Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private"
->> 1078 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    989 | createSQLException in     ''
|    975 | createSQLException in     ''
|    920 | createSQLException in     ''
|   2819 | initializeProperties in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl
|   3490 | initializeDriverProperties in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    823 | <init> .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
```

Any tips?

*I am using grails 2.1.4*

Comment: See if there's a newer instance of the JDBC driver JAR for JDK 7.

Comment: That's actually the first thing I did.
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in recent versions of the JDK - it fails in `jdk1.7.0_25` but I'm using `jdk1.7.0_21` and it works fine. **[Watch this issue for more information](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10183)**

Comment: Once again you've solved the charade. Downgrading to _21 fixed the problem. Thanks mate!